# Fallout 4 - Lost Deacon after completing 'The Nuclear Option'

Tags: fallout-4

I had Deacon as my companion while doing 'The Nuclear Option' quest and on completion (after exiting the Vertibird), he says something about seeing me back at Railroad HQ (at least, I *think* that's what he said). However, he isn't at Railroad HQ and is no longer my companion. I can't find him anywhere! I've been to every one of settlements and can't locate him.

Unfortunately, he's carrying a lot of decent weapons and I haven't reached max affinity with him yet so was hoping to carry on with him.

Any ideas how I can get him back?

Platform: Xbox One

Comment: If he was your companion, what happens when you try picking up a new one? Does it still give you the option to send him somewhere?

Comment: I must admit, I haven't tried that. I will try that tonight :-)

Comment: Hopefully it works for you. I'm not sure how this behavior works when they are part of a quest. So it's possible that this doesn't work... Or that you have to do that, then wait awhile to go to the HQ from wherever in Boston he's hanging out.

Comment: It's been about 2 game days since I completed the quest and no sign of him yet. Perhaps I am just being impatient but I would have expected him to have arrived back by now (all other people involved in the quest have arrived back).

Comment: No, that definitely should have been long enough. But I mean you might have to wait again after trying what I suggested. He likely wouldn't be instantly at the Railroad HQ.

Comment: Sanity-check: Which faction did you side with for The Nuclear Option?

Comment: I've been with the minutemen but I sided with the Railroad.

I tested your theory DangerZone....I requested Curie to be my companion and the dialogue came up asking me where I wanted to send Deacon. Success! Or so I thought. Curie was then nowhere to be seen!! I went to the settlement where I sent Deacon, found him, asked him to follow me which he did.....until I fast travelled somewhere and he was gone again.

So basically, it seems I can't have ANY companion after finishing that quest.

Comment: Now it turns out that Preston is an infinite loop about the institutes downfall and I can't complete any further quests with him!!!

Comment: The perks of being a buggy, yet top-rated games of the year.

Comment: It's a common feature of Bethesda companions, disapearing, rushing nowhere... it's called imprevisibility ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one situation that would be consistent with all the facts you've laid out, and it's not even really a bug.

If you told Deacon to wait for you after the Nuclear Option (which is not that hard to do accidentally), then he would just stay there and not come with you to the HQ, or the settlemnts, or anywhere else.

In comments, you added that

> I requested Curie to be my companion and the dialogue came up asking me where I wanted to send Deacon. ... I went to the settlement where I sent Deacon, found him, asked him to follow ... until I fast traveled somewhere and he was gone again.

This would also be explained by telling him to wait, although I'm not sure that that would hold up after dismissing him and recruiting him again.

I would go back to the settlement you sent him to, and see if you can tell him to start following you again.